# How Can Fetch data and get the length in griview.count

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to fetch data from an api. Here is the api link and response:

```
https://digital-display.betafore.com/api/v1/digital-display/displays/
```

Authorization Bearer:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3ODExNjkwLCJpYXQiOjE2Njc3MjUyOTAsImp0aSI6IjFmMjBkNDgyY2E3NzQzMGQ5MzM3ZjU3MTBlYjIzY2NhIiwiaWQiOjV9.QGvXtfHwWEJawAS-zIKo78UaCvMDr2lXx0796QcL_-4
```

Here is the Response:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Test",
                    "unit": null,
                    "price": "72000.00",
                    "sale_price": null,
                    "image": "/uploads/digital_display/products/Screenshot_from_2022-10-31_13-04-58.png",
                    "category": null,
                    "badge": null
                }
            ],
            "catalogs": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": null,
                    "unit": null,
                    "price": null,
                    "sale_price": null,
                    "image": "/uploads/digital_display/catalogs/survivor-series-2021_LSje3Zz.jpg",
                    "video": null,
                    "badge": null
                }
            ],
            "name": "asdas",
            "description": null,
            "category": "sdasdasd",
            "template_name": "dasda",
            "banner_text": null
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Test",
                    "unit": null,
                    "price": "72000.00",
                    "sale_price": null,
                    "image": "/uploads/digital_display/products/Screenshot_from_2022-10-31_13-04-58.png",
                    "category": null,
                    "badge": null
                }
            ],
            "catalogs": [
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "name": null,
                    "unit": null,
                    "price": null,
                    "sale_price": null,
                    "image": "/uploads/digital_display/catalogs/survivor-series-2021_ndrmDBX.jpg",
                    "video": null,
                    "badge": null
                }
            ],
            "name": "asdas",
            "description": null,
            "category": "sdasdasd",
            "template_name": "dasda",
            "banner_text": null
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Test",
                    "unit": null,
                    "price": "72000.00",
                    "sale_price": null,
                    "image": "/uploads/digital_display/products/Screenshot_from_2022-10-31_13-04-58.png",
                    "category": null,
                    "badge": null
                }
            ],
            "catalogs": [
                {
                    "id": 14,
                    "name": null,
                    "unit": null,
                    "price": null,
                    "sale_price": null,
                    "image": "/uploads/digital_display/catalogs/20220913_nxt_newlogo--52bc0a658df3cb6753ffd8b7da947690.jpg",
                    "video": null,
                    "badge": null
                }
            ],
            "name": "asdasd",
            "description": null,
            "category": "sdasd",
            "template_name": "sdada",
            "banner_text": null
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Test",
                    "unit": null,
                    "price": "72000.00",
                    "sale_price": null,
                    "image": "/uploads/digital_display/products/Screenshot_from_2022-10-31_13-04-58.png",
                    "category": null,
                    "badge": null
                }
            ],
            "catalogs": [
                {
                    "id": 15,
                    "name": null,
                    "unit": null,
                    "price": null,
                    "sale_price": null,
                    "image": "/uploads/digital_display/catalogs/survivor-series-2021.jpg",
                    "video": null,
                    "badge": null
                }
            ],
            "name": "Sony Bravia",
            "description": null,
            "category": "Restaurant",
            "template_name": "Sony Template",
            "banner_text": null
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Test",
                    "unit": null,
                    "price": "72000.00",
                    "sale_price": null,
                    "image": "/uploads/digital_display/products/Screenshot_from_2022-10-31_13-04-58.png",
                    "category": null,
                    "badge": null
                }
            ],
            "catalogs": [
                {
                    "id": 16,
                    "name": null,
                    "unit": null,
                    "price": null,
                    "sale_price": null,
                    "image": "/uploads/digital_display/catalogs/1033561.jpg",
                    "video": null,
                    "badge": null
                }
            ],
            "name": "asdas",
            "description": null,
            "category": "sdasdasd",
            "template_name": "dasda",
            "banner_text": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my controller where I used http package for fetching data from the api.

```
  Future<bool> getDisplays() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        "https://digital-display.betafore.com/api/v1/digital-display/displays/");
    var token = localStorage.getItem('access');

    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: {
        "Authorization":
            "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3NzYwOTY1LCJpYXQiOjE2Njc2NzQ1NjUsImp0aSI6ImE1ZjAyOTJlYTE1MjRhNDM5YzI2YWYwZGQzNjA3YjZlIiwiaWQiOjV9.yjKKzalzRvSrSiSBUhZtZVg3wBy_o7P2Wvy7sbMOOT0"
      });
      var data = json.decode(response.body) as List;
      List<DisplayModel> temp = [];
      for (var element in data) {
        DisplayModel displayModel = DisplayModel.fromJson(element);
        temp.add(displayModel);
      }
      _displays = temp;
      notifyListeners();
      return true;
    } catch (exception) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  List<DisplayModel> get displays {
    return [..._displays];
  }
```

Here is model:

```
class DisplayModel {
  String? status;
  List<Results>? results;

  DisplayModel({this.status, this.results});

  DisplayModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    if (json['results'] != null) {
      results = <Results>[];
      json['results'].forEach((v) {
        results!.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    if (this.results != null) {
      data['results'] = this.results!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Results {
  int? id;
  List<Products>? products;
  List<Catalogs>? catalogs;
  String? name;
  Null? description;
  String? category;
  String? templateName;
  Null? bannerText;

  Results(
      {this.id,
      this.products,
      this.catalogs,
      this.name,
      this.description,
      this.category,
      this.templateName,
      this.bannerText});

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    if (json['products'] != null) {
      products = <Products>[];
      json['products'].forEach((v) {
        products!.add(new Products.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['catalogs'] != null) {
      catalogs = <Catalogs>[];
      json['catalogs'].forEach((v) {
        catalogs!.add(new Catalogs.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    name = json['name'];
    description = json['description'];
    category = json['category'];
    templateName = json['template_name'];
    bannerText = json['banner_text'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    if (this.products != null) {
      data['products'] = this.products!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.catalogs != null) {
      data['catalogs'] = this.catalogs!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['template_name'] = this.templateName;
    data['banner_text'] = this.bannerText;
    return data;
  }
}

class Products {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  Null? unit;
  String? price;
  Null? salePrice;
  String? image;
  Null? category;
  Null? badge;

  Products(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.unit,
      this.price,
      this.salePrice,
      this.image,
      this.category,
      this.badge});

  Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    unit = json['unit'];
    price = json['price'];
    salePrice = json['sale_price'];
    image = json['image'];
    category = json['category'];
    badge = json['badge'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['unit'] = this.unit;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['sale_price'] = this.salePrice;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['badge'] = this.badge;
    return data;
  }
}

class Catalogs {
  int? id;
  Null? name;
  Null? unit;
  Null? price;
  Null? salePrice;
  String? image;
  Null? video;
  Null? badge;

  Catalogs(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.unit,
      this.price,
      this.salePrice,
      this.image,
      this.video,
      this.badge});

  Catalogs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    unit = json['unit'];
    price = json['price'];
    salePrice = json['sale_price'];
    image = json['image'];
    video = json['video'];
    badge = json['badge'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['unit'] = this.unit;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['sale_price'] = this.salePrice;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['video'] = this.video;
    data['badge'] = this.badge;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here is frontend where I tried to show but gettting errors.

here is the error I am getting : "Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0"

Here is the frontend code:

```
import 'package:digitaldisplay/controllers/DisplayController.dart';
import 'package:digitaldisplay/views/screens/CreateDisplay.dart';
import 'package:digitaldisplay/views/screens/CreateProduct.dart';
import 'package:digitaldisplay/views/screens/ShowDisplay.dart';
import 'package:digitaldisplay/views/widgets/NavBar.dart';
import 'package:digitaldisplay/views/widgets/Package.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:responsive_toolkit/responsive_toolkit.dart';
import 'package:responsive_grid/responsive_grid.dart';

import '../../models/DisplayModel.dart';
import '../widgets/Display.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const routeName = "/home";

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool _init = true;

  bool _loadingDisplay = false;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    if (_init) {
      _loadingDisplay =
          await Provider.of<DisplayController>(context).getDisplays();

      setState(() {});
    }
    _init = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  DisplayController displayController = DisplayController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final displays = Provider.of<DisplayController>(context).displays;

    final ButtonStyle buttonStyle2 = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF111111),
      shape: const StadiumBorder(),
      minimumSize: const Size(100, 50),
    );
    final ButtonStyle buttonStyle1 = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFc3232a),
      shape: const StadiumBorder(),
      minimumSize: const Size(100, 50),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFf5f5f5),
      drawer: const NavBar(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black),
        title: const Text(
          "Digital Display",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            color: Color(0xFF111111),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFe9e9ff),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const CreateDisplay()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text("Create Display"),
                  style: buttonStyle2,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                children: List.generate(
                    displays[0].results!.length,
                    (i) => DisplayCard(
                        displayName: displays[i].results![i].name as String,
                        displayImage: displays[i].results![i].catalogs![i].image
                            as String,
                        id: displays[i].results![i].id as int))),
          ),
          // Flexible(
          //   child: FutureBuilder(
          //       future: displayController.getallDisplay(),
          //       builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //         if (snapshot.hasData) {
          //           return GridView.count(
          //               physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
          //               crossAxisCount: 4,
          //               crossAxisSpacing: 5,
          //               children: List.generate(
          //                   snapshot.data?["results"].length, (i) {
          //                 return InkWell(
          //                   onTap: () {
          //                     Navigator.push(
          //                       context,
          //                       MaterialPageRoute(
          //                           builder: (context) => ShowDisplay(
          //                               snapshot.data["results"]?[i]["id"])),
          //                     );
          //                   },
          //                   child: DisplayCard(
          //                     id: snapshot.data["results"]?[i]["id"],
          //                     displayName: snapshot.data["results"]?[i]["name"],
          //                     displayImage: snapshot.data["results"]?[i]
          //                         ["catalogs"][0]["image"],
          //                   ),
          //                 );
          //               }));
          //         } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          //           return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
          //         } else {
          //           return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          //         }
          //       }),
          // ),

          // Flexible(
          //   child: FutureBuilder(
          //       future: displayController.getallDisplay(),
          //       builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //         if (snapshot.hasData) {
          //           return GridView.count(
          //             crossAxisCount: 4,
          //             children: List.generate(displays.length, (i) {
          //               return DisplayCard(
          //                 displayModel: displays,
          //               );
          //             }),
          //           );
          //         } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          //           return Center(
          //             child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
          //           );
          //         } else {
          //           return const Center(
          //             child: Text("Error"),
          //           );
          //         }
          //       }),
          // ),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text("Dashboard"),
                  style: buttonStyle1,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context)
                        .pushReplacementNamed(CreateProduct.routeName);
                  },
                  child: Text("Create Product"),
                  style: buttonStyle2,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text("Logout"),
                  style: buttonStyle2,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried this method but failed to fetch data for that error maybe I did something wrong in the code but I don't have any idea why I am getting an error like this. can you please explain the solution of the error? And How can I fetch data from the api?

Comment: print the data/response first before displaying in a gridView.

Comment: @john ok i am doing. I cheked the network I am getting 200 status ok though.

Comment: could you add your FutureBuilder widget too?

Comment: I didn't use future builder widget. @eamirho3ein. wait I am adding the whole code of the frontnend

Comment: @eamirho3ein I added the whole frontend code please check

Comment: your displays variable is null here. try use FutureBuilder instead of this way.

Comment: can you give me an code sample? @eamirho3ein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a few changes:

**In your controller, instead of:**

```
var data = json.decode(response.body) as List;
List<DisplayModel> temp = [];
for (var element in data) {
    DisplayModel displayModel = DisplayModel.fromJson(element);
    temp.add(displayModel);
}
```

**do:**

```
var data = json.decode(response.body);
    
List<DisplayModel> temp = [];

temp.add(DisplayModel.fromJson(data));
```

**and in the frontend part, in your `DisplayCard`, change:**

```
displays[i].results![i]
```

**to:**

```
displays[0].results![i]
```

Comment: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>' 

I am getting this error

Comment: @Sakibovi,  how have you initialized the ``_displays`` variable?

Comment: are you talking about this line ? :
List<DisplayModel> get displays {
    return [..._displays];
  }

Comment: If you can share a sample code it would be better for me

Comment: @Sakibovi, no I am talking about ``_displays``. What type of variable have you declared it?

Answer (score 1):

First change your `getDisplays` to this:

```
Future<List<Results>> getDisplays() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        "https://digital-display.betafore.com/api/v1/digital-display/displays/");
    var token = localStorage.getItem('access');

    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: {
        "Authorization":
            "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3NzYwOTY1LCJpYXQiOjE2Njc2NzQ1NjUsImp0aSI6ImE1ZjAyOTJlYTE1MjRhNDM5YzI2YWYwZGQzNjA3YjZlIiwiaWQiOjV9.yjKKzalzRvSrSiSBUhZtZVg3wBy_o7P2Wvy7sbMOOT0"
      });
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
        

      return DisplayModel.fromJson(data).results!;
    } catch (exception) {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

then use it like this:

```
Flexible(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Results>>(
          future: Provider.of<DisplayController>(context).getDisplays(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Text('Loading....');
              default:
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                } else {
                  List<Results> data = snapshot.data ?? [];

                  return GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      children: List.generate(
                          data.length,
                          (i) => DisplayCard(
                              displayName:
                                  data[i].name as String,
                              displayImage: data[i]
                                  .catalogs![i]
                                  .image as String,
                              id: data[i].id as int)));
                }
            }
          },
        ),
      )
```

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: No indices are valid Index out of range

Comment: can you print("length = ${temp.length}") in  getDisplays before return.

Comment: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following IndexError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<DisplayModel$>>(dirty, state:
_FutureBuilderState<List<DisplayModel$>>#ffe8c):
RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  FutureBuilder<List<DisplayModel$>>
  FutureBuilder:file:///home/mrsakib/Desktop/DigitalDisplay/digital_display/lib/views/screens/Home.dart:78:20

Comment: I am getting this exception I printed but no results

Comment: @Sakibovi did it fix your problem?